# Linking .h & .c Files to Main.c with WinAVR

Tags: c, avr, winavr

I am using WINAVR to progam an Amtel ATMEGA328 Chip.

I am trying to Link a library to my file but I am not sure exactly how to do it, and what I need to edit in the make file.

I have a lcd_lib.h and lcd_lib.c file that I want to include

in my  main.c i have #include "lcd_lib.h";

and I have those files in the same directory as my make filer & main.c file.

Answer (score 0):

Jeeze I am so used to being spoilt with C# and Java

My Solution:

in the make file:
find the line

SRC = $(TARGET).c [ADD FILENAME HERE]

so mine was:

SRC = $(TARGET).c lcd_lib.c